# Cannot update Composer's memory size

Tags: composer-php, magento2

I'm trying to install an extension on Magento 2 via Composer, but when I run Composer update, I get the following error:

```
 composer update

Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52
```

I try: 
`php -d memory_limit=-1 composer update`
But I get:
`Could not open input file: composer`

So I tried and got:

```
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
All settings correct for using Composer
Downloading...

Composer (version 1.9.0) successfully installed to: /home/customer/www/xxx/public_html/composer.phar
Use it: php composer.phar
```

So, thinking it's fixed I again tried and got:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Nothing to install or update
Package phpunit/phpunit-mock-objects is abandoned, you should avoid using it. No replacement was suggested.
Generating autoload files
```

So I tried composer update again and got:

```
composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer.phar/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleWatchGraph.php on line 52
```

So again, I try `composer update` and get 
    `Could not open input file: composer`

I'm right back to where I started and incredibly confused :/ Please advise. Thank you.

Comment: You are hitting a memory limit at around 2GB. Are you using 32bit PHP? Usually Composer tries to manage it's memory limits itself, but I'd assume that Magento is creating huge dependency graphs.

Answer (score 1):

When you are using `php -d memory_limit=-1` you are setting an `ini` entry on the fly but only for the script run via that command.

Your idea to run this command was close to what you want to achieve:

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 composer update
```

The only thing you have to know is the fact that `composer` works as a command because it stands somewhere your OS would look for all the executables (most likely `/usr/bin/composer`, `/usr/local/bin/composer`, or something the like, this is usually referenced as the `PATH`). But when you try to run `php composer`, then composer is just considered as a regular file, and your OS do not try to look in your executable path anymore.

What you can do still is to use the command [`which`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/which), that will return you the path to that `composer` executable.

```
$ php $(which composer) -V
Composer version 1.8.6 2019-06-11 15:03:05
```

So you should be able to achieve what you aim to do via

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 $(which composer) install
```

for installation of packages; and

```
php -d memory_limit=-1 $(which composer) update
```

for updates.

**Please also mind that**: there is a full article in the composer documentation about memory limit: https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors

That could possibly ease you job, changing the relevant `PHP CLI` setting, or that could point you at the usage of

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer install
```

and

```
COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer update
```

Comment: So tried it with the composer full path, and again, it looks like it works, but I still keep getting the insufficient memory warning when I try composer update